# Why doesn’t my DigitalOcean load balancer forward traffic to Parse Servers?

Tags: load-balancing, digital-ocean, parse-server

Today I created a load balancer and assigned to it 3 droplets (all 3 host parse servers), but it doesn't transfer the traffic to them. It doesn’t even pass the health checks!

All 3 of my parse servers, have 22 and 1337 as their only open inbound ports.

Here's the load balancer's setup.
[image: Screenshot-at-Mar-16-01-23-17.png]

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Digital Ocean, but this health checks setting looks wrong to me. If you request each of the servers directly on port 80 in '/', do you receive a successful response?

Comment: No, I don’t! Each request happens on 1337!

Comment: I love you! I changed the health check to 1337 and now it works!!! I thought it was an issue with my forwarding rules! Thanks!

Comment: Hi were you using ngninx

Comment: It's been quite some time since then, but I think not.